# How can I collect a list of out of date dependencies in GNU make?

Tags: makefile

I have some XML source files which need to be processed by a Ruby script to create generated c# files before my main target can be built. The start-up cost of script is much greater than the time to process each file so it's quite inefficient to process them one by one as is usually done in make files. What I want to do is collect them all together and pass them as a list to script which execute just before updating the main target.

What I have now is something like:

```
_generated_/%.xml.cs : %.cs
    #execute ruby script to generate .cs file

out.exe : a.cs b.cs _generated_/e.xml.cs ....
    #compile .cs files
```

I came across the idea of using eval for this so if the files which are processed have a suffix of .s and yield a file with a suffix of .t when processed by the script my idea was to do this:

```
%.xml : _generated_/%.xml.cs        
    $(eval SOURCE_FILES += $<)
```

However this rule won't trigger unless there is shell command after the eval  (echo will do) - I guess it's because make knows that simply calling a function can't possibly produce a file. Another idea I had was to collect the list of files into a temporary file instead.

```
    .INTERMEDIATE source_list.txt

   %.xml : _generated_/%.xml.cs        
        echo $< >> source_list.txt
```

While these will probably both work, I am wondering if there is a better way to do this.

Update:

What I ended up doing is was something like the following - the @ prefix on eval function fools make into believing that a shell command is being executed.

```
_generated_/%.xml.cs : %.cs
        @ $(eval DIRTY_XML += $(<))

out.exe : a.cs b.cs _generated_/e.xml.cs ....
        # Create generated cs files 
        # by running ruby script with DIRTY_XML as input 
        # Compile all .cs files
```

Answer (score 3):

Use an empty file called, say, `ruby-marker`, to indicate that all of the xml files have been processed. Its modification time can be compared to those of the "x.s" files. Then use `$?` to select only the prerequisite "x.s" files that have changed since the last run of the ruby script.

```
main-target: ruby-marker
    whatever...

ruby-marker: foo.s bar.s baz.s
    ruby-script $?
    @touch $@
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `$(filter)` on `$?` - `$?` is the list of prerequisites that are newer than target.

Comment: I have edited my question to make it what i am doing clearer. I tried this out, but if try to construct the list of out of date xml files from $? in the rule that compiles the .cs files then make complains it does not how make the generated .cs fiels. One way to make it work would be to have another rule in which the generated .cs files depend on the .xml files and rule just executes touch to create dummy generated .cs files so the second rule can then do the real work of geneating all of them in a batch before compiling them.